# <Apex:selectList> horizontal scroll

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an `<apex:selectList>` component that is overflowing. How can this component be configured to prevent this? Maybe a scrollbar or fixed width attribute for the apex component?

```
<apex:page controller="LicensingGridController" sidebar="false">
    <style>
        #header {
        color:White;
        text-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        width:80%;
        align:center;
        }
        #nav {
        width:15%;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
        color:black;
        }
        #section {
        width:80%;
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
        }
        .selected {
        color:black;
        }
        .selected:hover {
        color:blue;
        }
    </style> 

    <apex:form id="theForm" style="background-color:purple;">
        <div id="header">
            <b>Licensing Grid</b>
        </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <apex:pageblock tabStyle="License__c" >
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Filters:">
                    <apex:outputlabel>Something:</apex:outputlabel><br />
                    <apex:inputText title="Find" size="10"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="States:">
                    <apex:outputPanel style="overflow:auto;">
                        <apex:selectList id="statelist" value="{!States}" multiselect="true" size="10" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!stateFilter}" rerender="thePage" title="Filter" value="Filter" status="tbloading">
                        <apex:param name="offsetsize" assignTo="{!offsetsize}" value=""/>
                        <apex:param name="AccRendered" assignTo="{!AccRendered}" value="FALSE"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!resetFilter}" rerender="theForm" title="Reset" value="Reset" status="tbloading">
                        <apex:param name="offsetsize" assignTo="{!offsetsize}" value=""/>
                        <apex:param name="AccRendered" assignTo="{!AccRendered}" value="FALSE"/>
                        <apex:param name="bcsPaging" assignTo="{!bcsPaging}" value="TRUE"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageblock>
        </div>
....
```

Here is a screenshot of what is happening:
[image]

Comment: Did you try adding that `overflow:auto` style to the `selectList` itself?

Comment: This question is in regards to a salesforce visualforce page and apex component.  Moderator, please restore this question as this is 100% salesforce related.

Comment: It seems to be purely CSS related. The process is the same whether you are using html elements or vf. Right click, `inspect element`, add style properties until it renders properly. You should modify the `<select>` tag to add `width` and `overflow`. Tweak it until it looks right. Add those properties in a `style` attribute on the `selectList`.

Comment: This works for me: `style="width: 100px; overflow-x: auto;"`.

Comment: Considering this is about applying CSS on the rendered result of standard VF components I'm going to agree with OP here. @AdrianLarson it would make a good answer to explain that the selectList component renders as htlm select and how to apply style.

Comment: @MattM Did you try adding the `style` property? It seems like it should work just fine for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this `style` attribute works for me:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!states}" style="width: 100px; overflow-x: auto;">
```

**Before:**

[image: Before Screenshot]

**After:**

[image: After Screenshot]

It is scrollable in the "After" state, but macs hide the scrollbar until you're actually using it, for better or worse.